# Show that the Dini derivative satisfies $D^+(f(x),c)=-D_-(f(x),c)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ and show that for any point $c\in[a,b]$ we have $D^+(f(x),c)=-D_-(f(x),c)$.  Here $D^+$ and $D_-$ indicate Dini derivatives:
$$D^+(f(x),c)=\limsup_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$$
$$D_-(f(x),c)=\liminf_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$$

It seems like this is related to a change of variables.  If we write

$$ D^+(f(x),c)=\lim_{h\to 0^+} \sup_{0< t\le h}\frac{f(c+t)-f(c)}{t} $$

and set $i=-h$ then

$$ D^+(f(x),c)=\lim_{i\to 0^-}\sup_{i \le t < 0}\frac{f(c-t)-f(c)}{-t} = -\lim_{i\to 0^-}\inf_{i\le t<0}\frac{f(c-t)-f(c)}{t}$$

Now the lim and inf look like they need to for $D_-$ but the stuff on the inside looks wrong for the definition of the derivative. I know when the limit isn't handed that doesn't matter, but here it seems like it should matter--I should be able to simply change this to $\frac{f(c+t)-f(c)}{t}$.

---

I also have from a professor the following proof, which claims to establish the equality.

Let $g(x)=f(-x)$.

$$ D^+(g(x),c)=\limsup_{h\to 0^+}\frac{g(c+h)-g(c)}{h} $$
$$= \limsup_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(-(c+h))-f(-c)}{h} $$
$$=-\liminf_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(-c)-f(-c-h)}{h} =-D_-(f(-x),c)$$

However, as I try to prove the last equality, that seems to run into the same issue as above.

Comment: Isn't the last equality exactly the definition for $\mathrm D_- (f(-x), c)$? 

Comment: @xbh I thought $D_-(f(x),c)=\liminf_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$, at least that is the definition we're given.  Each difference quotient is given in that single form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be explicit,

\begin{align*}
&\quad \varliminf_{h \to 0^-} \frac {f(c + h) - f(c)}h \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0^-} \inf_{h \leqslant A \leqslant 0} \frac {f(c + A) - f(c)}A\\
&= \lim_{-h \to 0^+} \inf_{-h \geqslant -A \geqslant 0} -\frac {f(c - (-A)) - f(c)}{-A}\\
&= \lim_{k \to 0^+} \inf_{k \geqslant B \geqslant 0} \frac {f(c) - f(c-B)}{B} \tag {$k = -h, B = -A$}\\
&=\varliminf_{h \to 0^+} \frac {f(c) - f(c-h)}{h} 
\end{align*}